# how to solve the [] operator is not defind in the type object?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

**My Future builder occure error and i could not solved error yet any solve it please?.......................................................................................................................................................\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\**

```
pro.dart
 body:StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(

          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("orders")
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (c,snapshots)
          {


            return snapshots.hasData?ListView.builder
              (itemCount: snapshots.data.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (c,index)
              {

                return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(


                  future:

                  FirebaseFirestore.instance.
                collection("items").where("shortInfo",whereIn:snapshots.
                  data.docs[index].data()[EcommerceApp.productID]).//error occure here the operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object
                get(),
                  builder: (c,snap)
                  {
                    Map<String, dynamic> data1 = snapshots.data.docs[index].data();

                    return snap.hasData?AdminOrderCard(
                      itemCount: snap.data.docs.length,
                      data:snap.data.docs,
                      orderId: snapshots.data.docs[index].id,
                      orderBy:data1["orderBy"],
                      addressID:data1["addressID"],
                    )
                        :Center(child: circularProgress(),);
                  },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, dynamic> order = snapshots.data.docs[index].data();
// define order as above
return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("items")
    .where("shortInfo",whereIn: order[EcommerceApp.productID])
    //           use order here ^^^^^
    .get(),
```